# HTML table inside table hover on tr not working properly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table inside tr on child table I don't want to apply hover and zebra stripe, below is my code which is not working,  child table is showing hover and zebra stripe:

```
<table class='zebrastrip'>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <table class='atable'>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </tr>
</table>

   .atable tr:nth-child(2n-1){
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
   .atable tr:hover{
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
   }
    .zebrastrip tr:nth-child(2n-1){
        background-color:#f9f9f9;
    }
    .zebrastrip tr:hover{
        background-color:#fce4cc;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Then why are you wring css for .zebrastrip tr:hover?? Remove it if you don't want to apply for zebra srtip

Comment: for parent table i need background color and hove but for inside table it is not required

Comment: inner table hover is applying white color as your css. Isnt tat what u need?

Comment: ya but some hover on inner table tr is showing #fce4cc which need to be white/ffffff

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RbbAx/8/ this is the result of your posted code. it is fine here. Post a fiddle with your problm

Comment: You can't have a table sitting inside a TR. You should place your table inside a TD.

Answer (score 1):

fiddle of fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/r3eAn/

Fixed HTML:

```
<table class='zebrastrip'>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
          <table class='atable'>
            <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fixed CSS to have background of inner table always #fff:

higher priority for inner table styles

background of inner table defined

```
.zebrastrip tr:nth-child(2n-1){
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
.zebrastrip tr:hover{
    background-color:#fce4cc;
}
.zebrastrip .atable{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.zebrastrip .atable tr:nth-child(2n-1){
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.zebrastrip .atable tr:hover{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```